# Be in the size or have the size

Tags: meaning

> These images are in the size of 128 × 128 pixels and have 5 scales in curvelet domain.

> These images have the size of 128 × 128 pixels and have 5 scales in curvelet domain.

I saw the first sentence on the internet. Does it have the same meaning as second one I wrote? Which structure should I prefere while talking about the size of something.

Comment: The size of these images is [etc.]

Answer (score 1):

Neither works well for me, although I prefer the second. The first part of both is easy to understand and they have the same meaning. I do not understand the piece about *"have 5 scales in curvelet domain"* but it appears to describe some aspect of the images.

The phrase *"are in the size of"* is unusual. That sentance might be reworded as *"These images are of size 128 x 128 pixels ..."* or as *"The size of these images is 128 x 128 pixels ..."*.

Within the second sentance I would prefer the words *"... have a size of ..."*.